# Extracting number from alphanumeric string and adding them

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Given string str containing alphanumeric characters. The task is to calculate the sum of all the numbers present in the string.

Example 1:

```
Input:
str = 1abc23
Output: 24
Explanation: 1 and 23 are numbers in the
a string which is added to get the sum as
24.
```

Example 2:

```
Input:
str = geeks4geeks
Output: 4
Explanation: 4 is the only number, so the
the sum is 4.
```

I broke down the problem into smaller parts, for first I just want to extract the numbers.

```
s = "a12bc3d"

number = ""
for i in range(0, len(s)):
    if s[i].isdigit():
        n=0
        number = number + s[i]
        while s[i].isdigit():
            n = n+1
            if s[i + n].isdigit():
                number = number + s[i+n] + " "
            else:
                break
            i = i + n + 1
    else:
        continue


print(number)
```

my output from the above code is `12 23` but it should be `12 3`, as the for loop is starting from the initial point making 2 coming twice, I have tried to move the for loop forward by updating `i = i + n + 1` but it's not working out like that.
It will be great if someone gives me a direction, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `str.isdecimal()`.

Comment: You have to first put numbers in stack until reach an alphabet. Then extract digits as a single number and add it to sum variable. Do it until reach end of string

Comment: does the string "12" represent `1+2==3` or `12`?

Comment: @JonSG '12' is 12 not 3. Review example 1 in the question

Comment: @JCaesar, I understand that, but the code as they are structuring it does not look like it does to me.

Comment: General advice: ```range(0, 5)``` is equal to ```range(5)``` and putting ```else: continue``` at the end of your loop has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate the solutions with regex and group-by. And I got the solution using logic as well.

```
`s = "4a7312cfh86"
slist = [i for i in s]
nlist = []
for i in range(len(slist)):
    if slist[i].isdigit() and (i != (len(slist) - 1)):
        if not slist[i + 1].isdigit():
            nlist.append(slist[i])
        else:
            slist[i + 1] = slist[i] + slist[i + 1]
    elif slist[i].isdigit() and (i == (len(slist) - 1)):
        nlist.append(slist[i])

def addingElement(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return 0
    return addingElement(arr[1:]) + int(arr[0])


print(addingElement(nlist))

Output - 7402
```

Answer (score 3):

A slightly simpler approach with regex:

```
import re

numbers_sum = sum(int(match) for match in re.findall(r'(\d+)', s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.groupby` to break the string into groups of digits and not-digits; then convert the digit groups to `int` and `sum` them:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> def sum_numbers(s: str) -> int:
...     return sum(int(''.join(g)) for d, g in groupby(s, str.isdigit) if d)
...
>>> sum_numbers("1abc23")
24
>>> sum_numbers("geeks4geeks")
4
```

Comment: `sum_numbers("1aabc[³⁸]de33")`

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex.

```
import re
s='a12bc3d'
sections = re.split('(\d+)',s)
numeric_sections = [int(x) for x in sections if x.isdigit()]
sum_ = sum(numeric_sections)
print(sum_)
```